# Language Books/Tutorials for Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am a complete newbie in [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) . I have basic knowledge of Java, C#, .NET and now i want to learn [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) beacause of some reasons like [this](http://blog.groovymag.com/2009/01/why-groovy/) .

I have currently started it from [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Documentation) but trying to find something more on [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) like some tutorial,books,any interactive learning aid for beginners of [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) .

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the obligatory [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) link, which is a petty universal means of familiarizing oneself with a new language.  The problems are not ideal for learning the more macro aspects of programming ( OOP, Design Patterns, etc), but it will give you a good feel for Groovy's syntax and basic features.  I've ground through just shy of 100 of them, with definite results. - Plus, it was fun.

I'd also recommend the [Groovy Web Console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/scripts). You can use it to run your scripts online, but perhaps more importantly, you can browse the scripts of others - I've found this to be rather invaluable, particularly while getting acquainted with Groovy's DSL capabilities.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for online tutorials, I recommend reading the [Practically Groovy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=practically+groovy) series by Andrew Glover and Scott Davis, as well as the [Groovy Goodness](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/search/label/Groovy%3AGoodness) snippets by mrhaki which all provide plain, helpful and mostly up-to-date information about the important and pleasant language features.

Answer (score 3):

Shameless plug: I'm one of the co-authors<sup>1</sup> of [Groovy in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394842), which is pretty well regarded in Groovy circles, as far as I'm aware.

There's a [second edition](http://manning.com/koenig2/) in progress - if you order that now, you get early access to the second edition ebook as it's written, and a full copy of the first edition ebook to be going on with.

That said, of course there are plenty of other books around Groovy - with some particularly focusing on one area, such as Grails.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually I'm more like a glorified editor. While I've touched large portions of the text, I've written very few complete paragraphs, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, i would like to go for 'Groovy in Action' book.Hope it will be good for beginners also.

Comment: @Pratik: It starts from scratch, although it does largely assume that you're comfortable with Java.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was great help to me! still would look forward for any online tutorials(if any) like http://www.w3schools.com or so..

Comment: Make sure you get the second edition, because the first edition is very out-of-date