# I need some links for Groovy Tutorials

Tags: groovy

i need some tutorials to hence my knowledge in learning Groovy. I have been reading Groovy In Action book for the past one week, i found it very useful. But at the same time, i need some more tutorials for enhance my groovy knowledge, say articles about groovy, tips and tricks about groovy like that kind of stuff.

Cheers
Anto

Comment: possible duplicate of [Language Books/Tutorials for Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332481/language-books-tutorials-for-groovy)

Comment: I am voting to close this because *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good answer [Language Books/Tutorials for Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332481/language-books-tutorials-for-groovy)
I definitely agree on Euler Project idea in the accepted answer.

Comment: +1 The top two answers from that question pretty much cover it :-)

Comment: All the mentioned links are have very old content, i need a link, that is updated atleast once in a month!

Comment: @Anto. Which links have very old content? Project Euler have enough exercises to keep you occupied for at least a year:) mrhaki Groovy Goodness last post dated 15th of Jan. 2011!. Practicality Groovy has some very easy to read and understand articles. Basically all links in this answer are classic. Not sure then what are you looking for.